# Events not firing when value changes in Aurelia app

Tags: aurelia, aurelia-store

I have an Aurelia app using [Store](https://aurelia.io/docs/plugins/store/) to manage state between components.

In my dropdown component I have validation (not framework validation, just code which should get invoked in the ViewModel on change) which should fire when the value changes:

```
<select value.bind="parameter.value"
        change.delegate="valueChanged()"
        class.bind="isValid ? '' : 'has-error'">
        ... 
</select>
```

In the ViewModel the validation works like this:

```
@bindable() parameter: Parameter;

parameterChanged() {
    this.validate();
}    

valueChanged() {
    this.validate();
}

private validate() {
    this.isValid = this.parameter.value != '0';
}
```

The Parameter model looks like:

```
export interface Parameter {
    value: string;   
    ...
}
```

The `Parameter` is passed down to this component by a parent component where the value can change on a state object managed with Store.

The value can change when the following action gets invoked to change the value on the `State` object:

```
export async function changeValue(state: State, value: string) {
    const newState = Object.assign({}, state);
    newState.setup.parameter.value = value;
    return newState;
}
```

> When the parameter value changes on the state object the dropdown visibly changes on the screen, but `parameterChanged()` or `valueChanged()` do not fire.

Does anyone know what is happening here and anything I can try to resolve this? Any help appreciated...

Comment: For the `parameterChanged` to be fired, you need to add the `observable()` decorator to your field. I'm not sure here, but I think the change detection doesn't work if you change a field of an object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because I am using [Aurelia Store](https://aurelia.io/docs/plugins/store/) I should have been using a state changed subscription as follows:

```
@connectTo({
    selector: {
        parameter: (store) => store.state.pipe(pluck("parameter"))
    }
})

parameterChanged() {
    this.validate();
}
```

The reasons why this wasn't working as expected are:

- `valueChanged()` is bound to the *element's* change function, since the value is changing this will not fire.
- `parameterChanged()` does not fire because `parameter` hasn't changed, the `value` property of `parameter` is changing